# Color contrast formula ? (ImageMagick)

Tags: imagemagick

I reduced an image to 12 colors, annotated with some text (here it's color saturation, sorted) :

[image]

The text color is `%[pixel:p{10,10}*2]` (background *2) (I made a little script that I can share if you're interested).

As you can see, text is not very readable (contrast) in all cases (colors). Is there a smarter formula than a simple linear scaling to make text pop in all/most cases ?

Comment: You could try the complementary color -- just `-negate` the background color for the text.

Comment: You could measure the grayscale value of the color, then take either black or white for the text, whichever is furthest from the grayscale value.

Comment: -negate was the first thing I thought of. Doesn't work in all cases, try srgb(222,97,56) (negative is (33,158,199)). Your grayscale idea is interesting, sounds like a luminosity criteria ?

Comment: Using luminosity works ! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As per Fred's suggestion, using luminosity is much better. Using black & white text depending on luminosity > 56 or not :

[image]

And for a not colorful image :

[image]

The text represents L component of HSL value. Notice the change from black to white when value crosses 56.